# Por que não estou conseguindo buscar nenhum dado de uma tabela mysql

Tags: php, mysql

que erro há no Foreach?

```
<?php
    $banco = "mysql:dbnmae=banco;host=localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $senha = "";
    try{
       $conn= new PDO($banco,$user,$senha);
       echo "<h1>conectado com sucesso</h1>";
       $sql = " SELECT * FROM banco";
       $linha =$conn->query($sql);

       foreach($linha as $linhas){
           echo $linhas['nome'];
       }
    }
    catch (PDOException $e){
        echo "<h1>Falha ao conectar</h1>";

       $erro = $e->getCode();
      echo $erro;
    }
```

Comment: Você escreveu `dbnmae` ao invés de `dbname`

Comment: salvaste minha vida, muito abrigada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É um erro de escrita. Você escreveu `dbnmae` ao invés de `dbname`. Troque sua variável `$banco` para:

```
$banco = "mysql:dbname=banco;host=localhost";
```